# Animate colors in table cells Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have made a table using php. Here is the HTML generated code. 
http://pastebin.com/4X5RmA8B

I have 2 arrays in Javascript X and Y which corresponds for x and y coordinates of some cells. I want to change background-color of these cells dynamically using javascript. i.e. the color of each cell whose coordinates are taken from X and Y array gets changed after say 2 secs.
So the colors of the cells whose coordinates are in X and Y arrays keep on changing after 2 secs.
I am unable to change the color of cell using javascript. Please help me.

Comment: Change the colour how? Background, text? How does your JS look? Sorry, we will need more than that...

Comment: And the [tag:php] is *entirely* irrelevant to the question; please show us the rendered HTML ('view source'). How are these colours 'animated,' and in response to what event?

Comment: I have edited my question. Please have a look at it.

Comment: I am unable to change the color of any cell using jQuery.$(".x1y3").css("background-color","red");

Comment: @skjindal93 it works fine. Are you including the jquery library? http://jsfiddle.net/A9adj/

Comment: You don't need `jQuery` AND `$`. You should have simply `$('').css()` **or** `jQuery('').css()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSSs color transitions, OR you can use javascript property transitions, I would suggest you use a framework when dealing with animations in javascript.

though the ability to do that is not inherently available in plain jQuery... (i.e. jQuery Color).

from jquery website:

> most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic
>   jQuery functionality (For example, width, height, or left can be
>   animated but background-color cannot be, unless the jQuery.Color()
>   plugin is used)
>   http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: I am unable to change the color of any cell using jQuery.$(".x1y3").css("background-color","red");

Comment: make sure you correctly added the jquery plugin to your site.